# Google sheet api find by url

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I`m working with google sheet api and Im trying to check if my table has duplicate data for url. I have a column on my table called 'url' that contains urls like 'https://www.youtube.com/' and im using npm i google-spreadsheet node api.

My table example:

```
id | url
1  | https://www.youtube.com/
```

I tried:

```
sheet.getRows({
     offset: 0,
     limit: 10,
     query: "url = 'https://www.youtube.com/'"
  }, function( err, rows ){
     if(rows && rows.length > 0) {
         console.log('found')
     } else {
       console.log('not found')
    }
  })
```

This url is on the table, If I do that above with ID = 1, it find`s it. So the problem is to find url because of its format. I also tried to encode the url with

```
  encodeURIComponent
```

and didnt work.

How can I do this?
Thanks